# TinyMCE 4.0 Listbox submenu

Tags: listbox, tinymce, tinymce-4

I want to create a Listbox with a submenu but I don't know how to make a submenu.
The documentation on TinyMCE is crappy so that is why I ask it here.

This is my code:

```
editor.addButton('OwnStyling', {
    type: 'listbox',
    text: 'Stylesheet',
    icon: false,
    onselect: function(e) {
        editor.insertContent(this.value());
    },
    values: [
            {text: 'Menu item 1', value: 'Some text 1'},
            {text: 'Menu item 2', value: 'Some text 2'},
            {text: 'Menu item 3', value: 'Some text 3'}
    ],
    onPostRender: function() {
        // Select the second item by default
    }
});
```

At the place of the values I want to make a subitem with his own values.
Anyone knows how to do that?

Thank already!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like

```
{text:'Menu item', menu:[{text:'submenu1',value:'some value'},{text:'submenu2',value:'some value'}]}
```

For me it works on contextmenu but didn't try it on listbox!

Comment: Yes yes yes! After so much time shooting in the dark trying to write TinyMCE plugins based on pathetically minimal documentation, it was such a relief to have a question and find a working answer after only minutes!